# Impossible to save foreignKey with Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I'm using `Phpmyadmin` in order to handle my database and I get an error when I try to add a Foreign Key in my `llx_parts` table.

I get this error :

```
Erreur

Requête SQL:

ALTER TABLE `llx_parts` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `numero_adherent` ) REFERENCES `dolibarr`.`llx_societe` (
`code_client`
) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT ;

MySQL a répondu: Documentation
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dolibarr`.`#sql-58e2_29be`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-58e2_29be_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`numero_adherent`) REFERENCES `llx_societe` (`code_client`))
```

I don't understand where is exactly the problem ?

If someone could help me ?

Comment: You already have data in that table? If so then that's causing the issue. post both tables definitons and other related information

Comment: @Rahul Oh yeah I didn't try with an empty table ! I will look now

Comment: I get this error : `Error Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('dolibarr'.'llx_parts', CONSTRAINT 'llx_parts_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY ('numero_adherent') REFERENCES 'llx_societe' ('code_client'))` I have to look why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some data in table llx_parts ? You must have this error because llx_societe.code_client contains data that does not match with llx_parts.numero_adherent.

Comment: That's what exactly I said in a comment. Then why post the same as answer. This should rather be a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your agressivity. I began my message you have not posted yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**

That is happening because **llx_parts.numero_adherent** table has some of data and you are trying to add **numero_adherent** as FOREIGN KEY.

> Solutions:
>
> 1) Best possible way is you can delete all data from  **llx_parts** table and then try to add foreign key.
>
> 2) **numero_adherent** key data will contains some of value like null, 0 etc. that **dolibarr.llx_societe** table doesn't contains. so please remove those line, then try to add foreign key.

Hope this will help.